# Is it a good practice to set default values for created and updated date columns?

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating some tables and adding CreatedUtc and UpdatedUtc date columns. I previous project only set a default value for CreatedUtc.

Wouldn't make sense to also set a default value for UpdatedUtc as well?

Comment: Default values are totally dependent on your requirements, and without knowing what those are we can't comment. At a guess, this is a column that is set when a row is updated? If so, why *would* it have a value when it's first inserted? It's never been updated. But that's a complete guess at what you're asking here, and just an opinion (and they're off topic for Stack Overflow).

Comment: My opinion is "yes" but this is still opinion based.

Comment: On a previous project I worked on both the columns had a default value. Since you were creating and I guess updated at the same time.

Comment: No real requirement for this. I have seen it both ways and wanted to know what others typically do.

Comment: If you're on SQL Server 2016+ you can use temporal tables - ValidFrom will always be your WhenUpdated field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't set defaults on them at the database level.

I have come across cases when importing data from external sources where we don't have a created/last mod at for entries, and it didn't make sense to donkey vote them (e.g., doing so would cause issues with existing search models).

I let my Data Access Layer (DAL) handle setting and maintaining these columns.